# wrong validation message appearing in php/mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I got a  piece of code below where it performs certain php/mysqli tasks on validation and success. The problem I am having with the code below is that if the user enters in an incorrect username or email which is determined by a SELECT query, if there is no matching username and email then it should display the error message `Your Username or Email was not Correct`. But instead it is displaying this error message `An error has occured, your Email was not sent containing your new Password`.

My question is that why is it displaying the incorrect error message and how can I get it to dispaly the correct error message?

```
            if(isset($_POST['resetbtn'])){
                //get form data
                $user = $_POST['user'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];

 $errors = array();


if(!$errors) {

            $query = "SELECT TeacherUsername, TeacherEmail FROM Teacher WHERE TeacherUsername = ? AND TeacherEmail = ?";
            // prepare query
            $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
            // You only need to call bind_param once
            $stmt->bind_param("ss",$user, $email);
            // execute query
            $stmt->execute(); 
            // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
            $stmt->bind_result($dbTeacherUsername, $dbTeacherEmail);
            //get number of rows
            $stmt->store_result();
            $numrows = $stmt->num_rows();                                  

            if ($numrows == 1){

                   $pass = rand();
                   $teacherpassword = md5($pass);
                   $teacherpassword = substr($pass, 0, 15);
                   $teacherpassword = md5(md5("g3f".$pass."rt4")); 

                //update password in db   
                $updatesql = "UPDATE Teacher SET TeacherPassword = ? WHERE TeacherUsername = ?";                                            
                $update = $mysqli->prepare($updatesql);
                $update->bind_param("ss", $teacherpassword, $user);
                $update->execute();

            $query = "SELECT TeacherUsername, TeacherPassword FROM Teacher WHERE TeacherUsername = ? AND TeacherPassword = ?";
            // prepare query
            $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
            // You only need to call bind_param once
            $stmt->bind_param("ss",$user,$teacherpassword);
            // execute query
            $stmt->execute(); 
            // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
            $stmt->bind_result($dbTeacherUsername, $dbTeacherPassword);
            //get number of rows
            $stmt->store_result();
            $selectnumrows = $stmt->num_rows();

                            }else{
                        if(!$numrows){
                        $errormsg = "Your Username or Email was not Correct"; 
                        $user = "";
                        $email = "";
                    }
                }
        }


        if(empty($errors)) {
            if ($selectnumrows == 1){


                   $errormsg = "<span style='color: green'>Your Password has been Reset. An Email has been sent with your New Password</span>";


                    else{
                     $errormsg = "An error has occured, your Email was not sent containing your new Password";   

               }
           }
```

Below is the form:

```
            echo "<form action='./forgotpass.php' method='post'>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td id='errormsg'>$errormsg</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='user' value='$user'/><br/>".$error_user."</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='email' value='$email'/><br/>".$error_email."</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type='submit' name='resetbtn' value='Reset Password' /></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </form>";
```

Comment: -1 for using a code that you _got from somewhere_. Learn the basics.

Comment: Sometimes using the code that you find somewhere learn is in the path towards learning the basics!

Comment: Well, you (the OP) should at least indent the code and match the brackets properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that if $query returns no rows, first your $errormsg becomes "Your Username or Email was not Correct" and after that it changes to: "An error has occured, your Email was not sent containing your new Password".

The conditions are exactly the same (same query!), so if the first is true then the second one will be true as well. I'm not sure why you need two identical queries, but if you indeed need it, try changing the $errormsg variables in the last few lines to another variable (e.g. $errormsg2) and echoing them separately in the form.

Answer (score 1):

```
$numrows = $stmt->num_rows();
```

Should be

```
$numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
```

And

```
if ($numrows == 1){
```

Should be

```
if ($numrows === 1){
```

Comment: is the tripple = necessary? num_rows it should return an integer value, right?

Comment: It should, but what if it returns the string "zero" or "Error"? It will validate that way ( string "zero" == 1 ). It will probably not happen in this case, but it is good practice.

Answer (score 0):

`@John` mentioned one issue-

```
$selectnumrows = $stmt->num_rows();
```

needs to be in OOP style-

```
$selectnumrows = $stmt->num_rows;
```

(The `==` vs `===` is optional in your situation, but good practice)

---

But the reason you are getting - `An error has occured, your Email was not sent containing your new Password` instead of `Your Username or Email was not Correct` is because you are setting `$errormsg` in your 1st check and resetting it with your 2nd check. I have condensed you code and added `//Comments`

```
$errors = array();

if(!$errors) {  //This is returning true
  ...
  if ($numrows == 1){ //This is returning false
   ...
  }else{
     if(!$numrows){
         $errormsg = "Your Username or Email was not Correct";  //So this is getting set
         ...
     }
  }
}
if(empty($errors)) {  // But this is also returning true
  if ($selectnumrows == 1){   // And this is also returning false
      $errormsg = "<span style='color: green'>Your Password has been Reset. An Email has been sent with your New Password</span>";
  } //This closing '}' is missing in your posted code!!
  else{
       $errormsg = "An error has occured, your Email was not sent containing your new Password";   //So now $errormsg is being reset.
  }
}
```